# Redis replication for same variable

Tags: redis, replication, general-network-error

Let's say I have a variable that is being changed very frequently in the Master

```
set foo 1
set foo 5
set foo 4
set foo 8
set foo 4
set foo 10
set foo 7
...
```

If the network goes down, and more similar commands are executed, when network comes up, will the replica be flooded by all those commands, or will it receive only the last one for each different variable?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is each different variable ? ...

Comment: I mean variables like "foo1"; "foo2", etc. In my example I used only one : "foo".

Comment: Try to provide proper example and your expected output with same.

Comment: I already provided the example, and I don't have any expected output. It's a question, in case someone knows the answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Redis replication, it allows slave Redis instances to be exact copies of master instances. According to the Redis documentation, there are 3 main mechanisms:

- Master sends a stream of commands to the slave to replicate the dataset in the master side.
- When the link (between master and slave) breaks, for network issues or because a timeout is sensed in the master or the slave, then the slave reconnects and attempts to proceed with a partial resynchronization: it means that it will try to just obtain the part missed streams during the disconnection.
- If partial resynchronization is not possible, the slave will ask for a full resynchronization that means the master needs to create a snapshot of all its data, send it to the slave, and then continue sending the stream of commands as the dataset changes.

For more, see [here](https://redis.io/topics/replication).

Hope this will find you well.

Comment: Hello, Shudipta,  

I wan to to understand the second method. Imagine I have a variable "foo" that is being updated hundred times per second. If network goes down for 10 minutes, it will be 6.000 updates to transmit. When network recovers, will Redis send the stream with those 6.000 updates for same variable, or is it smart enough to detect it's the same variable, and send only the last command? As I wrote in my example, for variable "foo" :  

set foo 1  
set foo 5  
set foo 4  
...   
[6000 times]  
set foo 20  

Shouldn't it send only last one : "set foo 20"?
  
 Luis

Comment: The answer should be clear in the answer section provided above. You have master node with slaves. So when networks fails, even if they are not capable of communication among themselves, they will be updated the streams when they rejoin the cluster. That has been explained in the answer section. The more you can know from https://redis.io/topics/replication.

Comment: No, there is no answer to my question there. That is why I am asking here, in case somebody knows.
if all changes have been to only one variable, will the full stream with all changes to that variable be sent, or Redis is smart enough to send only the last update? 
I can imagine implementing that, it's not complex, and a very good optimization of the synchronization.

That is a question to the developers, I guess. Nobody here seems to know the answer.